# Ordering without JOIN from Second Table

Tags: mysql

I have a unique situation.  I have a function that generates SQl on the fly and runs it against the mySQL database.  It builds the SQL query step by ste and is highly complex.

It can have up to 40 different ANDs in the WHERE clause.  For example.

```
SELECT * FROM TableX   //yea I know  don't search for * ...  trying to save typing on stack.
WHERE  Size = 'Large'
AND color= 'blue'
AND smell = 'stinky'
AND ugly = 'no'
AND brand = 'United'
etc...
```

At the End it puts out a line of ORDER BY.  Such as:

```
ORDER BY brand
```

My challenge is that I can only ORDER using the ORDER BY *some string*.   This works just fine if I want to order the data from the primary table.  But what can I do if it comes out of a related table?

Say I have the following schema:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Trucks` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Make` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Current_PartList_ID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '1');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '2');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Mac', '3');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Mac', '5');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Daihatsu', '8');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '4');


CREATE  TABLE `Parts_lists` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Carb_Model` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Carb_date` DATE NULL ,
  `Tire_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Tire_date` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Hirsch', '2012-12-19', 'Toyo', '2013-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('HIrsch', '2013-02-14', 'Goodyear', '2011-03-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2011-11-04', 'Toyo', '2013-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Miller', '2009-10-11', 'Toyo', '2010-04-17');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2011-01-07', 'Goodyear', '2013-01-06');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2012-09-16', 'Lamb', '2012-06-25');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Miller', '2011-07-22', 'Unknown', '2012-04-07');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Davis', '2009-03-09', 'Hawking', '2012-06-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Sanno', '2010-01-07', 'Goodyear', '2009-07-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Thrust', '2012-11-11', 'Lamb', '2004-04-08');
```

I would Like to get:

SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'volvo' ORDER BY (*Parts_List.Carb_date*)

Thus giving me the following selection

```
ID    Make      (why)
6     Volvo     (Because the Carb_date is 2009-10-11)
1     Volvo     (Because the Carb_date is 2012-12-19)
2     Volvo     (Because the Carb_date is 2013-02-14)
```

To be very clear:  Im stuck with: The following text (I cant edit it at all: without a total rewrite of an archaic ugly app ):

```
SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'volvo' ORDER BY
```

I need a string for XXXXXXX

```
SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'volvo' ORDER BY   XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Using a `join` is exactly what you need to do. Why are you trying to avoid this?

Comment: Can your existing dynamic-SQL-writing function handle joins? If not, can you rewrite it?

Comment: @Mark Bannister.   I fear that I am going to have to rewrite the app.  Its old, long and ugly and in a language called Double Helix.  So I really am trying to avoid it.   It defiantly need to be scrapped, but I want to band aid it until I get budget to throw the whole thing out:  hire two new guys and rewrite form the ground up.

Comment: Can you add text to the **start** of the generated query, as well as the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as your `ORDER BY` string:

`(SELECT Carb_date FROM Parts_lists WHERE ID = Trucks.Current_PartList_ID)`

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Everything looks better in sqlfiddle. :)  (At least when it works)